# Is this a compound or sentence fragment?

Tags: sentence, north-american-english, compound-sentences, sentence-fragments

Given the following sentence:

"As if she lived in a castle and her favourite princes and princesses had just dropped by to visit"

Is this a compound or sentence fragment?

Comment: ... as if X and Y were true.

Comment: What function do you think *as if* serves in this excerpt?

Comment: It's a fragment—a dependent clause without an independent one. Here's an example of a whole sentence: *She acted as if she lived in a castle and her favourite princes and princesses had just dropped by to visit.*

Comment: It's a subordinate clause, introduced by _as if_. Take off the _as if_ and it's just another sentence.